# Select next element when the first initial element doesn't have a cetrain class CSS equivalent of this jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have the following jQuery. It loops over parent elements and then selects the first `div` without class `active`. From there, the next element is selected:

**jQuery**

```
$('.parent').each(function () {
    $('div', this).eq(0).not('.active').next().addClass('selected');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.parent * {
    padding-left: 1em;
    display: block;
}
.main {
    border-left: 2px solid;
}
.selected {
    color: #f00;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="main">First Span</span>
    <span>Second Span</span>
    <div class="main">First div</div>
    <div>Second div***</div>
    <div class="main">Third div</div>
    <span>Third span</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <span class="main">First Span</span>
    <span>Second Span</span>
    <div class="main active">First div</div>
    <div>Second div - dont select</div>
    <div class="main">Third div</div>
    <span>Third span</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <span class="main">First Span</span>
    <span>Second Span</span>
    <div class="main">First div</div>
    <div>Second div***</div>
    <div class="main">Third div</div>
    <span>Third span</span>
</div>
```

How could I do this without jQuery. I have a feeling there is some css4 selector to help. If not, a regular javascript answer will be awesome because i am trying to get away from this jquery.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: sorry, I added a minimized example. I basically want elements with 3 asterisks *** to be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of the [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)/[`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo classes to select the `div`. Then use the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) to select the next element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqqoc3s6/)

```
.parent div:first-of-type:not(.active) + * {
    color: #f00;
}
```

Since you said you wanted a JS equivilent to the jQuery you posted:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vpj8v0L5/)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.parent div:first-of-type:not(.active) + *');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (el) {
    el.classList.add('selected');
});
```